# Azure DevOps conditional can't evaluate Powershell set-variable

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops

I have a powershell script, which is not in a job, task, or stage, it's on its own. running in my DevOps build yaml like this:

```
- powershell: |
   if (//something that's irrelevant) {
    Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myCustomVar;isOutput=true]true"
   } else {
    Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myCustomVar;isOutput=true]false"
   }
```

After this powershell script, I have another script to echo out myCustomVar to see what the value is. Like this:

```
- script: |
    echo "What is my custom variable?"
    echo $(myCustomVar)
```

When the build runs, in the devops logs, it echos literally "$(myCustomVar)" and not either True/False

After that, I have a task which sends an email, but we only want to send an email if `myCustomVar` is true. So I use a conditional.

```
- task: SendEmail@1
  displayName: "Send email"
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables.myCustomVar, true))
```

however, this is breaking. I've tried a few other ways of doing it. `myCustomVar`, on the task condition, always returns NULL. Any help on syntax?

[image]

Comment: `Set-Variable` only affects the local scope of the running PowerShell task - you need to [output a special macro string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-variables-in-scripts) to set a pipeline variable from inside the script

Comment: I read about this but this only seems to work with jobs and stages, which I’m not implementing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use `##vso[task.setvariable]value` to set variables from a script in pipeline. The first task can set a variable, and following tasks are able to use the variable. The variable is exposed to the following tasks as an environment variable.

Check following useful links:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#setvariable-initialize-or-modify-the-value-of-a-variable
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-variables-in-scripts

Comment: I've tried to implement this. See updated post.

Comment: Try `$env:myCustomVar`.